# does upgrading .net framework changes Server Setting?

Tags: windows-server-2008, dotnet-framework

I need to upgrade .net framework in my Prod Server.earlier 3.5 is installed and I need to install 4.5. By installing the .net framework (4.5.1) Does it update any operating system settings? Will it change how the server runs?

Answer (score 2):

It's generally safe to upgrade .NET.   There are sometimes applications that make assumptions around a specific .NET behavior (usually bugs, but not always) so it's always a prudent decision to test those apps with 4.5 before applying the update.

To be clear, it won't change how the OS behaves, but it may adjust the behavior of installed .NET applications.

Comment: Will it have any impact on IIS Settings?any suggestion will be grateful.

Comment: It shouldn't impact a default IIS install in a noticeable way, but if you have apps running on top of IIS (ASP.NET/etc) then I would definitely do a compatibility test offline before performing the upgrade.